# React toastify text and close button is not aligned to the toast container

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

React toastify text and close button is not aligned to the toast container
[image]

This is the toast container in app.js and there is no

```
          <ToastContainer
            position="bottom-center"
            autoClose={5000}
            hideProgressBar={false}
            newestOnTop={false}
            closeOnClick
            rtl={false}
            pauseOnFocusLoss
            draggable
            pauseOnHover
            theme="colored"
          />



 export const showErrorToast = (message) => {
  toast.error(message, {
    position: "bottom-center",
    autoClose: 3000,
    hideProgressBar: false,
    closeOnClick: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    draggable: true,
    progress: undefined,
    progressStyle: { background: "#DBDBDB" },
    theme: "colored",
    style: { background: "#ED664B" },
  });
};
```

Comment: Did you add toaster css files?

Comment: @Ujjwal No, I haven't added any css file related to toast

Comment: did you added the css  `import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'` 
[as in this link](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/introduction)

Comment: @DineshMsd Yes I did

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was button css on a Login.css file, removing this solved the issue

```
button {
  background-color: #b10201;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```